# i want to see my temperatures and fan etc

Tags: 14.04, gnome, fan, temperature, lm-sensors

I downloaded `lm-sensors` and ran it. but i get that message:

```
$sensors    
"coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +44.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:         +44.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:         +43.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)"
```

but i cant see the others. I really need some help.

---

When i write `sudo sensors-detect` i get this:

```
This program will help you determine which kernel modules you need
to load to use lm_sensors most effectively. It is generally safe
and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions,
unless you know what you're doing.

Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no): y
Module cpuid loaded successfully.
Silicon Integrated Systems SIS5595...                       No
VIA VT82C686 Integrated Sensors...                          No
VIA VT8231 Integrated Sensors...                            No
AMD K8 thermal sensors...                                   No
AMD Family 10h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 11h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 12h and 14h thermal sensors...                   No
AMD Family 15h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 16h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 15h power sensors...                             No
AMD Family 16h power sensors...                             No
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             Success!
(driver `coretemp')
Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor...                         No
Intel 5500/5520/X58 thermal sensor...                       No
VIA C7 thermal sensor...                                    No
VIA Nano thermal sensor...                                  No

Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): y
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x2e/0x2f
 Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
 Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x4e/0x4f
  Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               Yes
  Found unknown chip with ID 0x8586

Some hardware monitoring chips are accessible through the ISA I/O ports.
We have to write to arbitrary I/O ports to probe them. This is usually
safe though. Yes, you do have ISA I/O ports even if you do not have any
ISA slots! Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (YES/no): y
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM78' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM79' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `Winbond W83781D' at 0x290...                   No
Probing for `Winbond W83782D' at 0x290...                   No

Lastly, we can probe the I2C/SMBus adapters for connected hardware
monitoring devices. This is the most risky part, and while it works
reasonably well on most systems, it has been reported to cause trouble
 on some systems.
Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no): y
Found unknown SMBus adapter 8086:9ca2 at 0000:00:1f.3.
Sorry, no supported PCI bus adapters found.

Next adapter: i915 gmbus vga (i2c-0)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): y
y
Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpc (i2c-1)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpb (i2c-2)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): y

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpd (i2c-3)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): y

Next adapter: DPDDC-A (i2c-4)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): y

Next adapter: DPDDC-C (i2c-5)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): y

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 1 at 4:00.0 (i2c-6)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): y

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 2 at 4:00.0 (i2c-7)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): y


Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue: 

Driver `coretemp':
  * Chip `Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)

To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
#----cut here----
# Chip drivers
coretemp
#----cut here----
If you have some drivers built into your kernel, the list above will
contain too many modules. Skip the appropriate ones!

Do you want to add these lines automatically to /etc/modules? (yes/NO)y
Successful!

Monitoring programs won't work until the needed modules are
loaded. You may want to run '/etc/init.d/kmod start'
to load them.

Unloading cpuid... OK


Base Board Information
Manufacturer: LENOVO
Product Name: Lenovo Z70-80
Version: 31900058WIN
Serial Number: PF07YFGG
Asset Tag: NO Asset Tag
Features:
    Board is a hosting board
    Board is replaceable
Location In Chassis: Type2 - Board Chassis Location
Chassis Handle: 0x0003
Type: Motherboard
Contained Object Handles: 0
```

Comment: Have you run `sensors-detect` ?

Comment: yes i have, then used "sensors" and it gives that message

Comment: Did it find any modules to load? You can see in `/etc/modules` if something was added

Comment: can you check my answer please?

Comment: It didn't recognize chip ID 0x8586. What is `lm-sensors` version?, what is your motherboard manufacturer and number?

Comment: i edited the code, at the bottom. can you check please

Comment: mm, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1933020 i tried that but it gave an error like this after 
    
sudo modprobe w83627ehf

"modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'w83627ehf': No such device"

Comment: is it due to any hardware limitations ?.  I do experience the same ?

Comment: i really dont know, i'm trying to find any solutions but no... it has been 4-5 hours :(

Answer (score 2):

Based on http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.drivers.sensors/37746 it seems your motherboard uses **ITE** chip `IT8586E` which unfortunately is not supported by `lm-sensors`. https://web.archive.org/web/20150813204337/http://www.lm-sensors.org/wiki/Devices

Answer (score -2):

Together with the `lm-sensors` package comes a script called fancontrol. It can be used to software-control your system fans.

The fancontrol script is treated as a service and should be found under `/etc/init.d/fancontrol`.

For more information read "Controlling fanspeeds" section in this [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SensorInstallHowto)

If you want a nice, powerful and customisable monitoring tool, you will fall in love on [Conky](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpConky) :)

Best regards,